# I want to take backup using RSYNC and never lose in backup machine

Tags: linux, rsync

I have my all important log files in **66 server** and want to take backup in **.40 server** using rsync.
**66 server** generates log every 5hours and using rsync i want to take backup in .40 server.

How can do i use rsync with particular options that takes all backup **66 ---> 40**, incase, 60 server lose some previous file but still all my files in 40 server remains same from beginning and take backup on daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by --delete option in rsync command. The destination (40 in your case) extraneous files will not be delete if you omit this option in rsync command.